# Download image php?

Tags: php, image, download, hyperlink

how do i make so when you click on this image you will begin to download it?

This is my code

```
            } elseif (isset($_REQUEST['animeinput']) && !empty($_REQUEST['animeinput'])) {

echo "<a href=\"sig.php?user=".$_REQUEST['user']."&anime=".substr($_REQUEST['animeinput'],0,32)."&color2=".$_REQUEST['color2']."\"><img type=\"image\" width=\"350\" height=\"100\" border=\"0\" src=\"sig.php?user=".$_REQUEST['user']."&anime=".substr($_REQUEST['animeinput'],0,32)."&color2=".$_REQUEST['color2']."\" /></a>";
```

Answer (score 4):

To prompt the browser to treat the request as a download, your sig.php needs to output a [Content-Disposition](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519) header as follows:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="suggested_filename.png"');
```

(I'll presume that sig.php is already output all other necessary headers like Content-Type etc)

Answer (score -1):

use

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
```

also look into `Content-encoding` and `Content-length`

Comment: Setting the content-disposition is the right thing to do, but you should use the correct content type rather than the generic "Umm, it's some data".

Comment: but it’s still downloadable! and some old browsers struggle without app/octet. and when downloading it is “just some data” and not images (to view) anymore …